# MigraDoc: How can i write vertical text?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, pdfsharp, migradoc

I got a paragraph and it renders fine on my pdf:

```
var para = currentSection.AddParagraph();
para.AddText("My text.")
RenderObject(docRenderer, XUnit.FromCentimeter(1.27), XUnit.FromCentimeter(22.86), "4cm", myParagraph);
```

Thing is i would like to write the paragraph vertically.

How can i achieve this using Migradoc and/or PdfSharp?

Comment: is [this helpful](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/XForms-sample.ashx) for you?

Comment: unfortunalty no because in this example they rotate images only

Comment: @Thariama That sample rotates text and images. Rotation applies to anything that is drawn using the `XGraphics` object.

Comment: true. actually i am trying to make it work but without success

Answer (score 1):

I made it (thx to PDFsharp Novice and Mong Zhu).
Here is the code in case someone else wants to write vertical text:

```
        XForm form = new XForm(this.currentGfx, XUnit.FromMillimeter(70), XUnit.FromMillimeter(55));
        XGraphics formGfx = XGraphics.FromForm(form);
        formGfx.DrawString("Test text", new XFont("Verdana", 6, XFontStyle.Regular), XBrushes.Black, 3, 0, XStringFormats.TopLeft);

        currentGfx.Dispose();
        currentGfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(this.currentPage);

        currentGfx.RotateAtTransform(270, new XPoint(15, 773));
        currentGfx.DrawImage(form, 15, 773, 200, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

It only requires `gfx.RotateAtTransform()` to rotate the current gfx. Afterward a new gfx should be used:

```cs
var para = currentSection.AddParagraph();
para.AddText("My text.");

// Rotate the text
gfx.RotateAtTransform(-12, new XPoint(15, 773));

// Render the paragraph
docRenderer.RenderObject(gfx, 0, 0, "12cm", para);

gfx.Dispose();
gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
```